# Coffeescript tag in javascript library questions?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I've been seeing a lot of questions tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and "some javascript library" (jQuery, backbone, prototype, socket.io), but when the question writer tags his question, he often neglects to add [coffeescript](/questions/tagged/coffeescript) even those his own code examples are written in CoffeeScript.

Just so I understand, and because I recently earned this privilege, would it be appropriate to add the [coffeescript](/questions/tagged/coffeescript) tag to these questions?  Somehow, I have my doubts, but because the two languages have become so interchangeable, if the user tags with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) but writes code in CoffeeScript, doesn't adding [coffeescript](/questions/tagged/coffeescript) make sense?  They are most certainly not synonymous, but if the user writes in one specifically, even if using libraries written in the other, shouldn't that language be in the tag list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true that CoffeeScript compiles into JavaScript, but the languages are different. The answer for a question about CoffeeScript would be different if the question were asked for JavaScript.

It makes sense to tag with [coffeescript](/questions/tagged/coffeescript) a question that is for CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 3):

If the question is about CoffeeScript, or CoffeeScript is mentioned in a way that is significant to the question, then it is appropriate to put the CoffeeScript tag on it.